# Interference of JAX-RS providers across independent JavaEE6 WARs in JBoss 6?

Tags: jax-rs, jboss6.x

I am working on two projects that I deploy as two WARs (each project in its own WAR). Both projects have in the WAR the same JAR that constitutes some common code.

Each project has a bunch of project specific JAX-RS provider classes.

It seems that I am experiencing some interference btween the providers of these projects when both projects are deployed. Either no provider is found (e.g. isReadable is not even called) or a provider from one project appears to be checked as applicable during requests to the other project (e.g. I see its isReadable() being called).

This happens a bit at random and the problem disappears completely when I only deploy one of the applications.

Questions:

Has anyone else see such behavior, too?

Am I doing something wrong or is this possibly just a bug in JBoss?

**Edit**: am I maybe having issues with this: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ClassLoadingConfiguration ?

Jan

Comment: How do you register the JAX-RS providers for each of projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer - it was a class loader isolation issue. Described here: http://jalg.net/2012/05/death-by-jboss-6-classloading/